# Where is Firefox's storage.local backend stored on disk?

Tags: firefox

It used to be in JSON files named `storage.js`, but [this changed in Firefox 63](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2018/08/03/new-backend-for-storage-local-api/).

Note that I'm asking about [storage.local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/local), which is used by WebExtensions, and not the similarly-named [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), which is used by websites.

(I'm running Ubuntu 18.10. However, I presume the file name and its location within one's profile folder is OS-independent, since Firefox appears to standardize profile organization across OSes. If not, it's still worth answering the question for each of Firefox's major target platforms, for the benefit of future readers.)

Comment: Please identify which OS you are using.  Please do not submit a comment, instead, edit your question to provide the necessary information required to answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound Done.